# Add Recipients on a Thread or Conversations

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to add Recipients to a Conversations or a thread without sending them a message which happens when I add them to the attribute newRecipients

```
"newRecipients": [{"emailAddress": {
    "name": "name-value",
    "address": "address-value"
  }}]
```

Anyone that could give me some guidance. The move Operation for a mail isn't available to use outside the outlook web app which makes it hard to copy a mail to an Office365 group. 
Would appreciate all the help I could get. This is for an outlook add-in.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You want them added as a Recipient but you don't want them to receive the message?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. 
The thing is that I want to copy the HTML body and Recipients from a mail an paste thus values into a new conversation to a group. Kinda like a copy.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible since it would inevitably result in misleading data. It would imply that someone received a message that they in fact had never received and were never even notified about.

Comment: Yes, but if someone received a mail that they wanna share with their group. This is possible in the outlook web. But no API calls for this is still existing.

Comment: Could you provide a link to this feature in Outlook for the web?

Comment: https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-roadmap?filters=%26freeformsearch=Groups%20#abc 
Look under rolling out

Comment: I accutaly found how I can move message to a group now the only problem is that I need to find the ID of the groups Conversation to be able to send the mail with move